# PlasticSCM Commandline check in

Tags: finalbuilder, plasticscm

So I am doing some automation of an Access Database project.  I run a script to compose or decompose the access database into a stub file and collection of text files that represent the forms queries etc...

Inside FinalBuilder I want to be able to check in these files.  But there is no way to know if the files actually have been changed by my script.

I am using the "PlascticSCM Check in Items" Action

```
CommandLine: cm ci "C:\Plastic\DuCombAccessDatabases\DucombCustomer.accdb"
The selected items are about to be checked in. Please wait ...
Error: There are no changes in the workspace c:\Plastic\DuCombAccessDatabases
Check In Items Failed.
```

So I don't understand why I get this error.  And what is the proper way to have it check in and ignore if there is an unchanged file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [what files have changed first](http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/kb-no-checkout-workflow.aspx):

```
cm findchanged -R . | cm ci - -c="comment"
# or
cm fc -R . | cm ci -
```

That way, you only check in *modified* files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using one of the latest Plastic SCM releases (> 4.1.10.359) you will be able to perform something like the following:

```
cm ci -a
```

All the changed/moved/deleted items will be committed.

If you have changed items by time-stamp and the content is the same (result of build process) the Plastic SCM server will discard them in order to prevent duplicated content revisions.